# Change image of PorterShapeImageView programmatically?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am using [this link](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) to shape `ImageView` but it only accept the shape that I have taken from drawable in xml and it can't be seem to change it programmatically?

**This is the code**

```
 <com.pmb.pipcamera.activities.PorterShapeImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_effect_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:siShape="@drawable/pip1_overlay"
            app:siSquare="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `PorterShapeImageView` is a descendant of the standard [`android.widget.ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html), so you should be able to change the image by using one of the `ImageView` methods:

```
mPorterShapeImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

mPorterShapeImageView.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);

mPorterShapeImageView.setImageIcon(mIcon);

mPorterShapeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_image);

mPorterShapeImageView.setImageURI(mUri);
```

Comment: i tried this one but no luck 
Drawable d1 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap_main);
        iv_effect_main.setImageDrawable(d1);

Comment: @user6428778 Huh, that's strange. I've never used this library, but it doesn't look like it overrides anything from `ImageView` that would prevent you from doing this. Did you try any of the other methods?

Comment: @user6428778 In the example provided in the library, Square's [`Picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library is used to set the image programmatically. `Picasso` uses the `ImageView.setImageDrawable()` method to do this, so these methods *should* work.

Comment: i tried that's why i told u.  And because of this shit i taken different shape view for all different shape-effect.  and check library issues on github people got same problem but yet not resolved ...